# what case dose hive reduce numbers only set to 1 in spite of users's setting ？

Tags: numbers, hive, reduce

**In  hive , such  as  order by ,count(1) ,the reduce numbers can only be  set to 1 . 
So ,what are the root cause  for  this ?   thanks**

Answer (score 0):

There are certain occasions when hive has to generate a map-reduce program that ultimately will use a single reducer.
For your cases :

1. `count()` : when executing a count operation the hiveserver eventually returns a single number to the client representing the amount of records. this single number, has to be returned from a single map-reduce program to the hiveserver.
   This restriction is translated into the fact that the final map-reduce of `count()` has to have a single reducer.
   From the performance side, this shouldn't bother you at all, the mappers in the pre-reducer part of this stage will use a combiner, so each mapper will count its own rows and the reducer simply will add the results of those counts (applies when `hive.map.aggr` is set)
   This behaviour has changed since hive 0.12, hive can skip the reducer part entirely when running count. look [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4002)
2. `order by` : running this, you are asking from hive to return the data globally ordered. When using the map-reduce execution engine, lets think how this order by can be done.
   The candidates are mapper or reducers for this operation. As mappers share nothing, no single mapper can generate an output containing the entire table, ordered, in the best case it can order its own split.
   Now we have the reducers, we can shuffle data from the mappers to the reducers, so the first option, is to shuffle all the data into a single reducers, where it can easily order it.
   The second option is to distribute it between different reducers, then each reducer can order only the data it received.
   For example, reducer #1 got this data `[3,1,6]` and reducer #2 got : `[5,2]` after sorting, reducer #1 will output `[1,3,6]` and #2 : `[2,5]`.
   Combining the two output togather will result with the **not ordered** set of `[1,3,6,2,5]`.
   The only way to make sure that multiple reducers, each sorting its own data, will result in a globally ordered result set, is to change the way the current map-reduce partitioner works.
   Currently data is passed from mappers to the reducers by the `hash` of the `key`, if we could shuffle the data in such a way that all the values less than 3 for example will go to reducer #1 and greater or equal to 3 will go to reducer #2 then, reducer #1 will output `[1,2]` and #2 : `[3,5,6]`.
   Combining the two output togather will result with the **ordered** set of `[1,2,3,5,6]`.
   So, in the original map-reducer programs, you could only use a single reducer due to the shuffle limitation. This also seemed to change from hive 0.12 ([here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1402)) but i didn't test is myself yet.